# Removing JTextFields after dynamically adding it

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

My goal is to delete two JTextFields at the same time by clicking a JLabel.

I've created the textfields like this:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


            inc++;
            txtName= new JTextField();
            txtNumber = new JTextField();
            txtName.setName("txtName"+inc);
            txtNumber.setName("txtNumber" + inc);

            pnlPanel.add(txtName);
            pnlPanel.add(txtNumber);

            if(count>0){
                x+=50;
                y+=50;

                txtName.setBounds(225,6+y, 182, 27);
                txtNumber.setBounds(35, 6+y, 182, 27);
                txtName.setName(tempBox+count);
                if(pnlTxtText.getComponentCount() >9){

                    pnlPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450+y,50+y));
                    pnlPanel.add(txtStudName);
                    pnlPanel.add(txtStudentNumber);

                    frmFrame.repaint();
                    scrpPanel.revalidate();
                }
            }
            frmFrame.repaint();
        }

    });
```

And this is my code for removing the textfields:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int countPlace= pnlPanel.getComponentCount();
    int countOfRemaining =countPlace;
    pnlPanel.remove(--countOfRemaining);
    frmFrame.revalidate();
    pnlPanel.remove(--countOfRemaining);
    frmFrame.revalidate();
}
```

});

Instead of deleting the txtfields on the same row, it deletes it one by one, i dont want that. Please help me. Thank you.

[image: To further understand my problem i posted a picture. Ever time I click a label, it should delete the last two fields but instead of doing that, it deletes txtfield from a different place]

Answer (score 2):

Call `pnlPanel.revalidate()` before `repaint()`

And don't use setBounds(). Define porper `LayoutManager` instead.

Comment: ;Hi. I added revalidate. What i can't understand is why this code:  int countPlace= pnlTxtTxt.getComponentCount();
    int countOfRemaining =countPlace;
    pnlTxtTxt.remove(countOfRemaining);
    frmGM.revalidate();
    frmGM.repaint();
   
    pnlTxtTxt.remove(countOfRemaining-1); throws this exception: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 8
    frmGM.revalidate();
    frmGM.repaint()

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this,

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int countPlace= pnlPanel.getComponentCount();
        int countOfRemaining =countPlace;
        pnlPanel.remove(countOfRemaining-1);
        frmFrame.repaint();
        pnlPanel.remove(countOfRemaining-1);
        frmFrame.repaint();
    }
});
```

Use this

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int countPlace= pnlPanel.getComponentCount();
        int countOfRemaining =countPlace;
        pnlPanel.remove(--countOfRemaining);
        frmFrame.revalidate();
        pnlPanel.remove(--countOfRemaining);
        frmFrame.revalidate();
    }
});
```

The above one throws an ArrayIndeOutOfBounds Exception because the count remaining variable is not being decremented after you remove a component. Hence the index goes out of bound when you try to remove the second time.

Comment: Hello, thanks. It removes 2 textfields, but it does not remove the textfields where i want to remove them. Why is that?

Comment: This code will only remove the text fields that were last added to the panel. Can you explain me properly how do you want the text fields to be removed? And which type is your panel's layout set to? Is it the default FlowLayout?

Comment: I posted the picture. Your code was right, I just cant understand why it does not delete the last two rows.. Please see my picture. Thank you!

Comment: the layout of this is Absolute Layout.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you add all of your `JPanels` to a Map (I use HashMap) in the form of `<Integer, JPanel>`. Name them all in order, and then just do `Map.remove(Map.size() - 1)` and `Map.remove(Map.size() - 2)`.

You can also get the current set of Integers (the keys) by doing a `Map.keySet()`;

```
Map<Integer, JPanel> temp = new HashMap<Integer, JPanel>();
temp.put(0, new JPanel());
temp.put(1, new JPanel());
temp.put(2, new JPanel());
temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
```

Makes it much easier to maintain numerous sets of panels. In my applications I don't control them numerically, but with short names instead.